# How can I tell my boss he has poor video meeting manners?

Tags: management, unprofessional-behavior, meetings, remote-work

My boss **loves** scheduling long, pointless video meetings. This is bad enough, but it's made worse by his poor manners and ridiculous rules.

- He doesn't like it when people mute their mic or use headphones ("you could be listening to something else than the meeting"), which turns meetings into a cacophony.
- He doesn't like it when people turn off their cameras, even if they have bandwidth issues, so meetings are laggy messes.
- He has a fan or something blowing directly into his mic.
- He eats with his mouth open during meetings, making a truly awful noise and you can see food spraying when he talks.
- The other day he kept putting the mic to his belly because he thought the intestinal noise was funny, but it's disgusting.
- He frequently interrupts people talking in the meeting to ask if everyone else is listening, or to just go off on a totally different tangent.

It's like I'm held captive. Even vendors have noticed and will ask him to i.e. mute his mic. He'll respond along the lines of "actually, could you please keep yours on? It's really rude to mute your mic."

Comment: What good do you think would come out of telling this to your boss?

Comment: I'm hoping he would stop doing these things.

Comment: Obviously your boss enjoys using his power to torment the people he manages. I doubt that he is unaware that muting your mic is good manners when every video conferencing etiquette guide I've ever seen says that everyone should mute their mike when not speaking. Does he exhibit this behavior when his boss is on the call?

Comment: Do you have deadlines to meet?  Does these meeting mean that you cannot make those deadlines, or have time been set aside for this?  If the first, you may ask your boss if you are needed at the meeting or if the deadline is more important?

Comment: This one made me laugh, wish our boss was as entertaining as that

Comment: Record those meetings, it will be great fun to watch later when you will have found a better position/manager...

Comment: This is just another psycho who's been entrusted to run a business, surprisingly common actually.

Comment: Seems like the standard workplace answer applies here: find another job. Sounds like a crappy place to work at / be. Jump ship into a better company. If you were just hired, don't even bother putting it on your resume. Otherwise, yeah ... not sure what happened.

Answer (score 7):

**Assuming it is a small company and the boss is the top-boss:**

Look for another job and if you want to burn that bridge let him know why you left, once you have the other contract. This is one of the rare cases, where I don't think internal attempts to fix the situation will be fruitful.

The only internal option I'd see is to try and band together with a few colleagues and behave appropriately ignoring his comments. E.g. just mute him when he's making disgusting noises and then ask him to repeat himself. Keep your cam of no matter what he says and tell him that he's inappropriate not you. This comes with the chance to get fired or otherwise find yourself in trouble. It is most effective if all of you do it, as boss then hardly can pick out one to retaliate and not promoting everyone will be hard when he needs people in higher positions etc.
But given the description of the boss, he's likely ignorant and arrogant enough to just keep arguing and setting up meetings to tell you he's the boss and what he says counts - which turns it into a fight of wills. Will you stick around just to fight this out, will your boss just fire you because he thinks it's funny and the like.

**If the boss is just a lower or mid-level manager:**

You can talk to HR or the boss's boss. Tell them how your boss a) is rude and b) is affecting your productivity. You may also ask them to send around guidelines on what video call etiquette is enforceable and what is voluntary (e.g. forcing cam on in home office can be questionable regarding privacy issues, depending on your local laws/culture). In this case there is a chance to changes something internally, but it will still be a hard fight, as your boss seems rather ignorant and arrogant, so they might start to hurt you in other ways out of spite even if you are right and get some support from HR or higher level bosses. This would mean a prolonged time where you need to note down any misbehaviour by your boss to report until either he caves and becomes reasonable or gets let go (or finds a way for you to be let go...). Again, any internal struggle against your boss has more chances of success if you can band together with co-workers. But you may need to prepare to jump ship either way.

Answer (score 2):

For this answer I assume you mean he is the top boss, and he has no manager above him

From what you described it doesn't sound like he'd be open to criticism of any sort, but if you can do anything I'd suggest focusing on things he might care about like reduced productivity and vendors' impressions. Bring up the topic but without mentioning anything at all about him specifically (or any other individual).

"We may be able to make meetings more productive if..."

"I got the idea that vendors might prefer if we used headphones to improve clarity"